# Safari (Win7) does not refresh img height with max-height property

Tags: css, safari

I have a grid in which I display images. Each image is supposed to adapt itself to the cell size.

I am using this css to adapt the image automatically :

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Then when I resize the div (cell) containing the image, the image should adapt to the div. It works properly under Chrome/Firefox.
On Safari 5.1.7 (Win 7), it works when changing the width of the div, but does not work for the **height**.

I created a sample case here : http://jsfiddle.net/MNL29/7/

The `height` button increases the height of the div, the `width` button changes the width and the image won't resize under Safari.

Why is this happening and is there a way around it (without Javascript) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New version

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Seems to be working as expected. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MNL29/13/)

Comment: No this does not work, check here : http://jsfiddle.net/MNL29/12/ it stretched the image

Comment: So you want that the image will keep it's proportions?

Comment: Yes. I want under Safari (win7) exactly what Chrome does on the jsfiddle I gave. Keep the ratio, grow as much as possible in the container div and grow/shrink with it

Comment: I'm testing it and it seems to work as expected. Do you have any insight as to why it does ?

Comment: I found it bizarre myself, so I don't even imagine a good explanation for this.

Answer (score 1):

in some browsers {height:100%} means that 100% are taken from parent-container and other browsers interprets that as 100% of the window. do all with jQuery like this:

```
$("#1").click(function() { 
  var width = jQuery('div.A').width();
  var wWidth = jQuery(window).width();

  if (width+30 < wWidth) {
    $("div.A").css("width", "+=30px");
  } else {
    $("div.A").css("width", wWidth);
  }
});

$("#2").click(function() { 
  var height = jQuery('div.A').height();
  var wHeight = jQuery(window).height();

  if (height+30 < wHeight) {
    $("div.A").css("height", "+=30px");
  } else {
    $("div.A").css("height", wHeight);
  }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/MNL29/8/)

Comment: Thanks but it does not fix the issue in Safari. You are assuming that my div height is higher than the window but it's not so you javascript code always does what mine do.

Comment: Do you mean that the image must have the size of the outer div? Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/MNL29/9/ but without stretching the image, right?

Comment: Yes, but your example stretched the image. That's why I use `max-width` and `max-height` which works on Chrome/Firefox and as I explained, not on Safari for the dynamic height. Did you test my jsfiddle in Safari to compare?

Comment: If you don't want stretching, why you have 2 buttons, one for width and one for height? Without stretching you just need one button called `zoom` or something like that. And this button increases height and width, right?

Comment: My buttons are here to show what happens if I resize the div by height or width. I want to be able to increase **only** the height of the container and have the img fill properly the div without stretching (keeping the ratio). Exactly what my code does on Chrome in the jsfiddle

Comment: Which case? The example you gave? No I tested it under Safari and it does not increase the image height when the container's height is increased

Comment: On Chrome, when I click on the button `height` my image becomes bigger as there is more space for it to grow. On Safari, my image does NOT change at all. When I click on the button `width` it changes in both browsers

Comment: Yes, I have Safari Version 6.0.2 (8536.26.17) and there it is the same... But when the image-origin-size is reached, the DIV-container is growing but not the image anymore.

Comment: Ok so on my side I have the latest Safari for windows 7 I could find (5.1.7) and it does not work. Are you on Mac OS ? I'll update my question to reflect this. Thanks !

Comment: Yes, Mac OS X (Mountain Lion). Do you know this nice helper? http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: Ok so at least now I know it's a windows problem (or limited to version 5.X). But I still need to find a way to fix it.

Comment: I know it can work in Javascript by computing the ratio, that's what I was doing at first. But now I wanted to do this in full html/CSS. It's written in the question to not use JS. Anyway someone find a correction for me. But thanks a lot for helping me!